# g-brief2 separatorlines not justified - (trennlinien nicht bündig)

Tags: letters, letterhead

The separatorlines `\trennlinien` in g-grief2 class are not justified (flush with the the other components of the letter) like in the g-brief class. The first line seems to be to much on the right hand side compared to the other two lines, makeing the letter look wired. This doesn't look nice. can this be fixed ? how ? Here is what I mean:

Die `\trennlinien` im g-brief2 sind nicht bündig wie sie es im g-brief sind.
Die erste Trennlinie fängt weiter rechts an als die im Adreßfenster und die unterste.
Das sieht unästhetisch aus. Kann man das beheben ? wenn ja wie ? Hier das meine ich:

[image: example of trennlinien in g-brief2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\ps@firstpage}{\put(0,-8)}{\put(-9,-8)}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@firstpage}{165mm}{180mm}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This updates the `firstpage` page style to move the header rule left and extend it. The modification is similar (when considering horizontal similarities) to the same style in `g-brief.cls`.

[image]

An adjustment does not seem necessary for subsequent page style (given in `regularpage`). However, if needed, add

```
\patchcmd{\@oddhead}{\put(0,0)}{\put(-9,0)}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@oddhead}{165mm}{180mm}{}{}
```

between the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair. It's necessary to patch `\@oddhead` since `g-brief2` loads `\AtEndofClass{\pagestyle{regularpage}}`.